# Приходит пустое поле photo при загрузке изображения во ВКонтакте через API

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Отправляю изображение на сервера ВКонтакте через метод `photos.getWallUploadServer`, на что в ответ от сервера мне приходит ссылка для загрузки. Загружаю по этому адресу изображение:

```
request.post({
        url: urlToUpload,
        formData: {
            photo: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + imgAddr)
        }
    },
    function(err, response, body) { console.log(body) });
```

На что в ответ от сервера получаю следующий json:

> {"server":840630,"photo":"null","hash":"c0cae5e00d018400382e1a84b05d4a44"}

При этом, ещё вчера загрузка изображений работала, а сегодня почему-то перестала. Это я неправильно загружаю изображение? В документации такое поведение API не задокументировано.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `photo` в `formData` использовать `file1`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie попробовал, не сработало. Да и в документации сказано, что отправлять файл нужно в поле photo: `Поле POST-запроса: photo`

Comment: Почему бы не заюзать [`vk-io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vk-io)?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie зачем мне ставить целый модуль ради решения одной мелкой проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

сталкивался с такой же проблемой написал ровно такой же код и у меня работает.Может у вас просто нет этого файла по пути которому вы указывает в createReadStream, или попробуйте убрать промежуточный слэш

Comment: Этот ответ не тянет на ответ, поскольку вы лишь высказываете предположение (это лучше делать в комментариях под вопросом)